# Is 1h10m enough time to transfer at Dublin airport?

Tags: transit, dublin, short-connections, dub

I'm travelling from Newcastle to USA and transferring at Dublin.

The entire trip is with Aer Lingus. They quote a time gap between landing and take-off at Dublin of 01h10m. They assure me the timings are OK.

Are they right or should I worry?

Comment: Please don't write in all caps.

Comment: 1:10 is fine, but it doesn't really leave you time for shopping or much waiting around. You'll want to go directly to US preclearance _no later_ than 45 minutes before departure, and signs in Terminal 2 will tell you when to go to preclearance.

Answer (score 2):

Dublin Airport isn't that busy at all. Apparently there is a separate line for  Transfers. As you are not changing the airliner I don't see any problem. If you are holding EU Passport then the queue will clear off very quickly.

Comment: Transfers is only open in the morning though, but it doesn't take long to go out of customs and upstairs and back in again

Answer (score 1):

if it is with the same company and you don’t have to re check you baggage then I don’t see any problems, but you have to be aware that they might be delays do weather or others conditions, if you have to re check your baggage I find it pretty difficult so I would advise you against unless the airline takes responsibility for you to be on time or else send you free of charge in a another

Comment: Is there if difference if it's the same airline company or not and what could be the differences?

Comment: when they are different airlines they usually blame the other airline for arriving late and won’t take responsibility but if it is the same airline they usually take the blame and try to put you on the next plane,  I been on both and on the first case I had to buy another ticket.

Comment: Oh that's indeed very unfortunate. Thanks for explaining since I'll have a few transfers myself soon on my trip and they're different airlines I thought.